# Do a Microsoft Bot in Azure need any specific Permissions to write in a Table Storage?

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, azure-storage

i was wondering if a bot needs any permissions to write in a Table Storage in Azure.
Is a bot able to write in a storage with only the Table Name and the access key Secret or do the bot need more permissions by default? Do i need to configure something in the App Registrations inside AD?

Im asking because i am working with the bot framework SDK and i am at a point, where the bot can send messages to the storage account and save the data there, but only when i test the bot locally via Visual Studio and the Bot Framework Emulator. If i publish the same code to a web app bot and test it in the interface in Azure, the data wont get stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's basically 2 options to grant access to Azure Storage Tables as found in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/storage/common/storage-auth):

1. Using a SAS token
2. Using the access key

So as far as authorization goes you should be fine using the access key. Of course there's other things that could block your access in particular connectivity (e.g. firewall on the storage).

Comment: Correct. I'll add that from the Bot Framework side of things, we don't officially support Table Storage, just [Cosmos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#using-cosmos-db) (more expensive, more performant) and [Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#using-blob-storage).

Comment: There's [community JavaScript support for Table](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-js/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-storage-azure-table/README.md), though.